# Google drive API v2 upload fails

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to upload to a Google drive using Google Drive API v2, vb.net 2015,
Windows 10 Pro ver 1909.  My code throws an "**Error: redirect_uri_mismatch**" when the following 'CreateService' procedure is called:

```
Public Sub CreateService()
   Dim ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxe9gqt7105uofe6q1hmks4e89m.apps.googleusercontent.com"
   Dim ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
   '
   Dim MyUserCredential As UserCredential = _
       GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(New ClientSecrets() _
       With {.ClientId = ClientId, .ClientSecret = ClientSecret}, _
       {DriveService.Scope.Drive}, "user", CancellationToken.None).Result
   Service = New DriveService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() with _
       {.HttpClientInitializer = MyUserCredential, .ApplicationName = "My Drive"})
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have your application listed as an authorized redirect URL in google?

Comment: 0


I'm not sure. I've been to the API console to set up an account and obtained OAuth credentials OK. But do not know how to get a redirect URL or a redirect URI. I'm missing something somewhere!